# call jquery function from rails controller based on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to set the inner html of an element based on some condition. i.e.

```
    if cond
      js('$("#my-id").html(a)')
    else
      js('$("#my-id").html(b)')
    end
```

I found page.replace_html, but it's deprecated for rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have remote request coming in to the controller (with remote: true), use:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js do 
    if cond
      render text: '$("#my-id").html(a)'
    else
      render text: '$("#my-id").html(b)'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Given only `a` and `b` are changing here, might be worth collapsing this into a `#{cond ? 'a' : 'b'}` type inline.

Comment: Thanks, but I already have a render in this action. I'll provide some context: I need to display a "Loading.." image, until some preview is loaded, and then render the preview

Comment: The answer is correct as per your question posted. There is nothing written about wanting to display 'Loading...' and neither does page.replace_html does any 'Loading...' thing. Nonetheless, you will have to handle the 'Loading...' image thing by binding to ajax:beforeSend and ajax:success and showing/hiding the loading image there. See more about these events at: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax